# How do I fix Symfony 6 Error "Input value contains a non-scalar value"

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony6

I am working with Symfony 6 forms. I tried submitting the form using the `submit()` method. From the documentation [Symfony Form Direct Submit](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/direct_submit.html) the cause of the error is spelled out as "**The list of fields submitted with the submit() method must be the same as the fields defined by the form class. Otherwise, you'll see a form validation error:**". How do I debug and in fact, solve this kind of error?

Comment: Can you provide your example ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the errors of the form with `$form->getErrors()`.

Using the following `$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));`should fail with the recent changes of the component. Returning an array from the get method fails with the non-scalar error message.

Instead, you have to use either this

```
$allValues = $request->request->all();
$form->submit($allValues[$form->getName()]);
```

or this, more condensed,

`$form->submit($request->request->all()[$form->getName()]);`

Comment: it is possible to pass the form name as an argument:
`$request->request->all($form->getName()));`

Comment: @Jokūbas, you have an error in your solution,  one extra ')' :) But thanks for the shortcut